# ios - mask the scroll view's superview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mask, uipangesturerecognizer

[image]

[image]

I have implemented the clipping mask effect and the image is draggable but the issue is that image and mask image is moving simultaneously, I want to drag the image which is below the mask layer and mask layer should not move.

Please suggest me to get the exact result of the gif image.

Comment: Can you post the code you've used so far?

Comment: CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m0_mask.png"];
    maskLayer.contents = (id)maskImage.CGImage;
    maskLayer.frame = _MyView.bounds;
    maskLayer.bounds = (CGRect){CGPointZero, maskImage.size};
    _MyView.layer .mask = maskLayer;

Comment: @ASV Have you solved this?